# Booting does not work

Tags: boot

I recently had my ubuntu installed and I'm still learning the software. Today when I turned my computer on I get the screen this:

- Ubuntu with linux 3.2.0-38-generic
- Ubuntu with linux 3.2.0-38-generic (recovery mode)
- Previous linux versions
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

I've tried every option and no success. I didn't install it so I don't have any disks. What happen and can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean with 'no success'. What actually happens?

Comment: What did you try to do? Did you try 'up' and 'down' keys or 'enter' and it didn't work?

Comment: The first one I tried was recovery mode. I used arrow to go down and then enter. Can I post a picture ? I think that would be easier  for everyone to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This grey screen appears if an error occurred during the last shutdown.
The first option 'ubuntu with linux 3.2.0-38-generic' should start ubuntu as expected. 
If ubuntu doesn't start with the first option, you'd have to select recovery mode, but without further info it's not possible to give further instructions.